# Trying to calculate difference between two date in format (00-00-0000 00:00:00 ) in minutes in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have date in following format `a_time=01-06-2020 15:28:06`  &  `b_time=01-06-2020 15:39:00` in table t_mst 
and i want to convert diff of given values in queries in minutes

```
select (extract( day from diff )*24*60*60 +
         extract( hour from diff )*60*60 +
         extract( minute from diff )*60 +
         extract( second from diff ))/60  total_Minutes
    from(select b_time - a_time diff
           from t_mst Where a_time between (trunc(sysdate, 'mm')) and (sysdate))
```

But getting Error "Invalid extract field for extract source"
any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I have removed [tag:sql-server] as the above is clearly not valid T-SQL, and thus I am making the assumption it's Oracle.

Comment: "Format" only applies to how the dates are **displayed**; it has no relevance to your computations. Formatting is only applied at the very end, when the query results are displayed on the screen.

Comment: By the way, your computation - if it had worked - would have been entirely wrong. Why are you multiplying hours, for example, by 60 * 60?  That will convert from hours to seconds, not to minutes. Same for converting days. Funniest is your conversion of minutes to themselves by multiplying by 60. That gets first place.

Answer (score 2):

The error you show means that `b_time - a_time` worked. Which means they are in `date` (or perhaps `timestamp`) data type; that is good.

Then, they must be `date`; if they were `timestamp` then the difference would be `interval` data type, and you can indeed extract time elements from `interval`. So, the error message suggests that the data type of `a_time` and `b_time` is indeed `date`.

Now: In Oracle, the difference between two dates is a `number` (in days); you can't extract time elements from a number. Instead, consider that the difference is already a number of days (including a fractional part); to convert it to minutes, you only have to multiply it by 1440 - and then round the result, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged with 3 databases and the code is for postgreSQL. I assume you meant, postgreSQL:

```
select (extract( epoch from age(a_time, b_time)/60)  total_Minutes
    from t_mst 
--Where a_time between (trunc(sysdate, 'mm')) and (sysdate))
```

If you need it casted to int:

```
select (extract( epoch from age(a_time, b_time)/60)::int  total_Minutes
    from t_mst
```

PS: Not sure you meant plSQL or PL\pgSQL.

Answer (score 0):

If `b_time`and `a_time` data types are `DATE` you can simply run

```
select (b_time - a_time) * 24*60 AS total_Minutes
from t_mst 
Where a_time between trunc(sysdate, 'mm') and sysdate
```

In case they are `TIMESTAMP` data type you have to extract the values, e.g. like this:

```
select 
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM (b_time - a_time))*24*60
    + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (b_time - a_time))*60
    + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (b_time - a_time))
    + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (b_time - a_time))/60
    AS total_Minutes
from t_mst 
Where a_time between trunc(sysdate, 'mm') and sysdate
```

Comment: second query as you mentioned is throwing error  "Invalid extract field for extract source"

Comment: Are you sure both `b_time` and `a_time` are `TIMESTAMP` data types?

Comment: yes i am sure both are in given format a_time=01-06-2020 15:28:06  and b_time=01-06-2020 15:39:00

Comment: I did not ask for your current session default **display** format, I ask what is the **data type**?